# Decimal to hex conversion

Tags: c++

I need to write the following program:
I have a long non-negative integer is given(4 byte). Delete from the hexadecimal digit less than 5.
But I do not know where to start.
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
    unsigned int x=10012;
    char hexString[32];
    cout<<hex<<x<<endl;
    itoa(x,hexString,16);
    cout<<hexString;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(hexString);i++)
    {
        int a = hexString[i];
        if(a < 5)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<strlen(hexString)-1;j++)
                hexString[j] = hexString[j+1];
                i--;
        }
    }
    cout<<hexString;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `But I do not know where to start` How about start writing some actual code? Then we can help you.

Comment: of course, i add my code

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can you give some step-by-step example of what you expect the output to be for a given input?

Comment: May I suggest operating on a `std::string`? It is much easier to remove characters from a `std::string` than a `char` array and there are functions in the `<algorithm>` library that can do what you want on a `std::string` in a couple lines of code.

Comment: I have number of decimal notation me need in this number of hex  notation, delete number  < 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different way of thinking about the problem: Don't use strings at all.

```
unsigned int filter(unsigned int x)
{
    if(x < 5) // no more digits worth keeping. Time to head back and collect results.
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (x%16 < 5) // exclude this digit
    {
        return filter(x >> 4); // return what we already have collected
    }
    else //include this number
    {
        return (filter(x >> 4) << 4) + x%16; // make room, collect digit.
    }
}
```

`filter` will call itself with one less digit (the least significant digit is removed) until there are no digits left worth collecting. Each call to filter looks at the least significant digit and decides to keep it by adding it to the end of the number that's been accumulated on the way back or reject it.

More obvious (and should be just as fast once optimized)

```
unsigned int filter(unsigned int x)
{
    if (x < 5) // no more digits worth keeping. Time to head back and collect results.
    {
        return 0;
    }
    unsigned int digit = x % 0x10; // isolate least significant hex digit
    unsigned int remaining = x / 0x10; // remove least significant hex digit
    unsigned int collected = filter(remaining); //process remaining input
    if (digit >= 5) // collect this digit
    {
        collected = collected * 0x10 + digit; // make room and add digit.
    }
    return collected;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain in more detail why "x >> 4" and "(x >> 4) << 4) + x%16"?

Comment: @Notail `x>>y` shifts `x` to the right `y` bits, making the number smaller. `0xA5 >> 4` will remove 4 bits, one nybble, resulting in 0x0A. << shits left `0xA5 << 4` will produce 0xA50, making room to insert a new nybble. Shift too far in either direction and bits fall off the end and are lost.`filter(x >> 4)` calls the `filter` function with one less nybble, so all `filter`ever has to look at is the least significant nybble. Less book-keeping.

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator. It gives the remainder in integer division. `x%16` divides `x` by 16 and returns the remainder. Hexidecimal numbers are base 16, so this is like dividing a base 10 number by 10 and keeping the remainder. It isolates the least significant digit. Eg: `0xA5 % 16` = `0xA5 % 0x10` = 0x05, so you isolate the least significant nybble. I will rewrite the question to make all of this more obvious.

Comment: what is "nybble"?

Comment: @Notail A nybble is 4 bits, one hex digit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (total shot in the dark cause your question is quite unclear):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    unsigned int x=10012;
    char hexString[32];
    char buf[32] = {};
    sprintf(hexString, "%x", x);
    cout<<"Hex String: "<<hexString<<endl;
    for(int i=0, j=0;i<strlen(hexString);i++)
    {
        // Convert from ASCII value to int
        int a = hexString[i] - '0';
        if(a > 5)
        {
            buf[j] = hexString[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"With nothing greater then five: "<<buf<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I took your code, made it work for your specifications, and you think the answer you can not understand is better?  I guess it is what I get for trying to help you :-(